# Java: Collections.max return largest number error

Tags: java, numbers, max

Given a loop, I want to print the largest number four times. There are `total_A`, `total_B`, `total_C` and find the largest number among these three. But I'm facing some problems of getting the correct maximum number. The output for data training no.1 and no.4 are correct which return the largest number, but no.2 and no.3 are wrong. Below is my output:

**Updated output**

[image]

Below is my code:

```
public class Multiclass2 {
   public static void main(String args []){
      double x [][] = {{3.24,-0.96},
                     {-1.56,-0.61},
                     {-1.1,2.5},
                     {1.36,-4.8};

    double [] wA = {0,1.94,3.82};
    double [] wB = {0,-4.9,-4.03};
    double [] wC = {0,4.48,3.25};

    double threshold = 1;
    int n = x.length;
    double total_A = 0;
    double total_B = 0;
    double total_C = 0;
    List<Double> li = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double max = 0;



    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        System.out.println("For training data point no." + (i+1));

            total_A = (threshold * wA[0]) + (x[i][0] * wA[1]) + (x[i][1] * wA[2]);

            total_B = (threshold * wB[0]) + (x[i][0] * wB[1]) + (x[i][1] * wB[2]);

            total_C = (threshold * wC[0]) + (x[i][0] * wC[1]) + (x[i][1] * wC[2]);


            li.add(total_A);
            li.add(total_B);
            li.add(total_C);
            max = Collections.max(li);

            System.out.println(total_A+", "+total_B+", "+total_C);
            System.out.println("MAx is "+max);


    }



}
}
```

Comment: Where does `number` come from?

Comment: Well, the code does not compile and would not produce the output you've shown us even if it compiled so... We need real code for giving real answers

Comment: Please provide an MCVE; i.e code that we can compile and run for ourselves, sample input, and the **expected** output for the sample input.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: The output for no.1 and no.4 are correct. But somehow no.3 and no.4 the output are the same with no.1 which are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same collection accross the entire loop, so you're calculating the max of ALL data points. You made two code style mistakes which allowed this bug to happen:

- firstly, you did not choose the appropriate scope for your variables. Since they're local to the loop, they should be declared inside the loop, not outside
- secondly, constructing a collection for calculating the max of a fixed, small number of numbers is overkill. Just use `Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c))`

The corrected code would be:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double x[][] = { 
        { 3.24, -0.96 },
        { -1.56, -0.61 },
        { -1.1, 2.5 },
        { 1.36, -4.8 } 
    };

    double[] wA = { 0, 1.94, 3.82 };
    double[] wB = { 0, -4.9, -4.03 };
    double[] wC = { 0, 4.48, 3.25 };

    double threshold = 1;

    int n = x.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("For training data point no." + (i + 1));

        double total_A = (threshold * wA[0]) + (x[i][0] * wA[1]) + (x[i][1] * wA[2]);
        double total_B = (threshold * wB[0]) + (x[i][0] * wB[1]) + (x[i][1] * wB[2]);
        double total_C = (threshold * wC[0]) + (x[i][0] * wC[1]) + (x[i][1] * wC[2]);

        double max = Math.max(total_A, Math.max(total_B, total_C));

        System.out.println(total_A + ", " + total_B + ", " + total_C);
        System.out.println("Max is " + max);
    }
}
```